# Check if the email template really exists in SendGrid before sending the email

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am trying to send emails using SendGrid email service using Dynamic Templates.

I am using SendGrid version 7.2.

```
"sendgrid/sendgrid": "^7.2",
```

Sending emails is working great and I am able to send emails successfully using the below code.

```
$this->mail->setTemplateId($templateId);
$response = $this->sendGrid->send($this->mail);

if ($response->statusCode() != 202) {
    throw new \Exception("Failed to Send Email.");
}
```

The problem is sometimes the `$templateId` can be an invalid or belong to a deleted template.

I looked through the internet for hours and searched the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to check if the email template exists before trying to send the email?
Or maybe to retrieve a list of active email template ids from SendGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ["Retrieve paged transactional templates" API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/transactional-templates/retrieve-paged-transactional-templates) to get all (dynamic) templates to check if there is one that matches your ID.

```php
<?php
// Uncomment next line if you're not using a dependency loader (such as Composer)
// require_once '<PATH TO>/sendgrid-php.php';

$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
$query_params = json_decode('{
    "generations": "legacy",
    "page_size": 18
}');

try {
    $response = $sg->client->templates()->get(null, $query_params);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $ex->getMessage();
}
```

or via `cURL`

```
curl -G -X GET https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>>" \
--data-urlencode "generations=dynamic" \
--data-urlencode "page_size=18"
```